# How to generate thumbnails of the playing video as tooltip when user puts the mouse on seekbar in jw player?

Tags: jwplayer, thumbnails

I am playing a video and i want to show thumbnail of the video of that particular time as user puts the mouse on the seek bar as tool tip, i am using jw player to play videos and i want this to be done today itself, can anyone help me in doing this, if you know any add on of jwplayer which does this, please let me know, i can purchase it also, but really wanna get this done today.I will really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess those video thumbnails are some extra data apart from the video that these video players uses to show them when you move mouse over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jwplayer is not having any such thing at present, you can use youtube api to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Tooltips Thumbnail is now supported in JW6.

JW Player 6 uses WebVTT files to load Tooltip Thumbnails. WebVTT is a plain text format, part of the HTML5 standard, that's also used for providing Closed Captions. These VTT files contain links to the actual thumbnails, which can be in JPG, PNG or GIF format.

> VTT Example
>
> Here is an example VTT file. It belongs to a 20-second video, for
>   which 4 preview thumbnails are included:
>
> WEBVTT
>
> 00:00.000 --> 00:05.000 /assets/preview1.jpg
>
> 00:05.000 --> 00:10.000 /assets/preview2.jpg
>
> 00:10.000 --> 00:15.000 /assets/preview3.jpg
>
> 00:15.000 --> 00:20.000 /assets/preview4.jpg

Check JWPlayer site for more info here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31778/adding-tooltip-thumbnails/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.